# How to add button in plotly to control the graph

Tags: plotly, plotly-python

I want to draw graphs from the CSV file using plotly. (which has multiple columns to draw) . How to add a button/tick/GUI-control so that I can control which are the columns I want in the graph.

I'm using Plotly-python module.

Comment: How did my suggestions work out for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some options:

1. [Custom buttons](https://plotly.com/python/custom-buttons/)
2. [ipywidgets](https://plotly.com/python/figurewidget-app/)
3. [Plotly-Dash](https://plotly.com/dash/) and [Dash Core Components](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components)
4. [Plotly-Dash](https://plotly.com/dash/) and [HTML-buttons](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-html-components/button)

Which one you should use will depend entirely on your use-case.